# jQuery Combobox with Grid plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Can someone kindly suggest a jQuery ComboBox plugin with autocomplete functionality and Grid as its dropdown? It should ofcourse have feature to load data remotely. Though I liked the plugin from usability perspective and tried implementing it [ComboGrid](http://combogrid.justmybit.com) but somehow I have failed. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: try `select2` (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Comment: @Stiger, thanks for the suggestion but the plugin suggested by you doesn't meet my requirement of multi-column dropdown (GRID) in the combobox.

Comment: It's provide `formatSelection` and `formatResult`, I think you can put your template html there (in this case, it's grid)

Comment: @Stiger, thanks for the hint. Will surely try your suggestion.